# How to acquire a public IPv4 and apply it to ubuntu server?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, linux-networking, ip

I want to host my website, but I don't know how to allocate a public IPv4 address. I have public IPv6 address, but not a public IPv4. I heard of the IPv4 exhaustion and that I may need to buy an IPv4. How/where do I buy one and once I do, how do I apply this IP to a machine running Ubuntu Server 20.04-3 LTS?

Thanks.

Comment: It sounds more like you have an ISP that has assigned you an IPv6 address and not an IPv4 address, because if you've actually purchased an IPv6 block, you would know to purchase an IPv4 block from a broker, and you should already know how to do that if you purchased an IPv6 block. You have to talk to your ISP about getting assigned an IPv4 address or use an ISP that provides an IPv4 address.

Comment: Rent a VPS or something and  host in the cloud. Or use the VPS as a reverse proxy.

Comment: planty off topic

Comment: @Paul I have a public IPv6 address assigned by my router through DHCP. My router has a public IPv4. Through port forwarding, I can use this as a public IPv4 for one of my web servers. However, I need more than 1 public IPv4 to host my app. I was wondering if there was a way to purchase IPv4 and assign a member of the CIDR to my machine. There is very little information on the internet regarding how to acquire a public IPv4 and apply it, which is why I am asking here. Is the only way to get additional public IPv4 by contacting my ISP?

Comment: Your question is off-topic for Server Fault. What you want to do is set up a local reverse proxy. You may need a more sophisticated network gateway, such as pfSense.

Comment: Contact your ISP.. buying/selling IP blocks are not allowed last I looked.

Comment: @NiKiZe There are several guys out there like these guys: https://www.ipv4.global/, but that isn't what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You do not. PERIOD.

IPv4 addresses are assigned in blocks, a single IP is not available OUTSIDE OF YOUR ISP (who distributes a block he has).

The whole concept of the blocks is because those blocks are the granularity of the routing tables - to keep them from growing out of control with individual IP addresses being routed.

So, talk to your ISP.